# Podcast sounds to iTunes

Tags: php, html, javascript, xml

I need to upload our sounds to iTunes using rss feed.Created rss feed,i don't know how can work this with iTunes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you lookin for help in how to set up an RSS feed in way iTunes understands, in subscribing to an RSS feed within iTunes or something completely different?

Comment: yes.For testing purpose i have create an rss feed but  after to connect itune and linking with rss steps confused me.

Comment: I'd like to see this reopened. Could you edit the post to include a link to Apple's service you are using? Are you a vendor selling songs through iTunes Connect? Are you integrating iTunes (a specific version and OS) with a playlist of some sort?

Comment: Or mmaybe add a short full sample of the rss feed you've set up?

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [Apple's documentation](https://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html)? The page contains a link you can use (from a machine with iTunes on it) to upload the RSS-feed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know, but the page simply links to rather complicated deep link which I think is even more likely to change (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/publishPodcast).